Horizontal product card
Please help me to develop following horizontal product card with HTML and CSS:

It should contain image and two text sections separated with vertical separator (~80% card height).
I've tried numerous solutions, ie Flexbox, but the main issue remains non working vertical alignment, which I cannot solve.

The point is that SO is not a free coding service. You're expected to do your research, show your attempt preferably as a [mcve], and demonstrate the problem you faced. You want to learn flexbox BTW.

Not the type of question you should be asking, but here, I think this is waht you are looking for, I just put a random image into it


body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
  border-radius: 8px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.badge {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 8px;
  background-color: #ffc107;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.image-section {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.image-section img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.text-section {
  flex: 2;
  padding-left: 16px;
  text-align: center;
}

.main-text {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.sub-text {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #777;
}

.divider {
  width: 1px;
  background-color: #dcdcdc;
  height: 60%;
}

.another-text {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}
<div class="card">
  <div class="image-section"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/dd/Square_-_black_simple.svg/500px-Square_-_black_simple.svg.png" class="obj"></div>
  <div class="text-section">
    <div class="main-text">Text</div>
    <div class="sub-text">Sub text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="divider"></div>
  <div class="another-text">Another text</div>
</div>




Thanks a lot. It solves the main issue with vertical alignment I've had so far.. Sorry for not being too specific, but this is a great piece of code for me to continue!

Glad I could help, let me know if you need any other help with this
